# Cannot add attachment file to email from c#

Tags: c#, windows, email, attachment

Need to open email client with attached file from c# program.

Next c# sample cannot open email client (Outlook) with attached file and show error message

> The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are
>   using.

```
[Test]
public void FileToEmailClient()
{
    string testDataFilePath = @"..\..\Data\test.txt";
    Assert.That(File.Exists(testDataFilePath), Is.True);
    string subject = String.Format("File {0} attached", Path.GetFileName(testDataFilePath));
    string body = "body";
    string command = String.Format("mailto:?subject={0}&body={1}&attachment=\"{2}\"", subject, body, testDataFilePath);
    Process.Start(command);
}
```

Comment: from a quick internet search, outlook doesn't seem to support attachments. and also, you might need to specify the email address.

Comment: From Windows Explorer I can with help of context menu command "Send To | Mail recipient" open Outlook with attached file. So, I want to implement same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if "mailto" is the right command but I think you should be able find answer on [Command-line switches for Outlook for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-for-Windows-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6)

Try this (please replace with your values like path of Outlook.exe)

```
var outlookPath = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\OUTLOOK.EXE";
var command = @"/a ""C:\Temp\Signature.txt"" /m ""to@me.com&cc=cc@.com&subject=subject&body=body""";
Process.Start(outlookPath, command);
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Without "attachment" section the command works: opens Outlook with defined subject and body. But I need send email with attached file.

Comment: Ignore C# for a moment and just try dropping to a command line, `cd`'ing to the Office directory and try running `OUTLOOK.EXE` with the `/a` switch passing it a file. For me that works just fine.

Comment: I tried next command from Windows menu Run mailto:?subject=File test.txt attached&body=body&attachment="..\\..\\Data\\test.txt" and same error shown

Comment: Try running this from your Run command `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /a "C:\Temp\Signature.txt" /m "to@me.com&cc=cc@me.com&subject=subject&body=body"` assuming this is the right path for your outlook exe and you have folder named Temp in your C drive and it has file called Signature.txt

Comment: I don't want to call Outlook.exe, I want to open default email client

Comment: yes, published c# sample (via Outlook) works, but I want to implement via default email client.